# Create short unique IDs (chars and numbers) that 'looks' pretty... like YouTube IDs (PHP)

Tags: php, encryption, hash, url-shortener

I want be able to generate an unique string id from an integer.

So for example '1' is converted to 'o7wu' and vice-versa. (use the number to search the DB and the string for display)

I found this great function: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/, but the generated ids are really **ugly** for small numbers, for example
**'1' is 'aacd' and '2' is 'aadd'**. I also found http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash, the generated ids look great, but they are 'one way' only, i think.

I dont really need any kind of encryption, I just need it to be short, pretty.

**For those having truble with my deffinition of a pretty ID:** I define pretty as real random mix of chars and ints. NOT: aabb33, abc123, aa22cc. YES: dfh7, ao8f, z6t4 .. and so one...

Comment: why does ugly matter? *o7wu* is pretty and *aacd* is not - you must be a modern art critic

Comment: BTW I am a modern art critic :) I define pretty as real random mix of chars and ints.. aabbc, 11aac, 1a2b3c are NOT pretty, w9d6a, qi51m and ap3o ARE pretty, even beautiful.

Comment: If you're really concerned with their "prettiness" just make a map of numbers to what you find to be a pretty string. Also, I don't quite see how changing a 1 to "o7wu" is shortening it by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @Jonathan: `aaaaaaa` is just as 'random' as `qi51m`. You probably want less 'true' randomness ;-)

Comment: @jprofitt: Try harder, give your imagination a try: something like 9999999999 converted to asjt3.

Comment: google comes up with a few hundred scripts for this, try them all until your find one that pleases. or just concentrate on making good website.

Answer (score 1):

Random number generators can be hacked to give less random numbers.  Actually, you can make them use the same numbers every time.  If you set the seed to the same number, you will get the same sequence.  Here's an example that creates a "random" string by passing a single number.

```
<?php
$n = 1;

// Any number to be added to the random seed
// Different numbers give different sequences
$offset = 45;

srand($n + $offset);
$code = '';

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    // Numbers and letters
    $char = rand(48, 57+26);

    // Lower case letters
    if ($char > 57) $char += 39;
    $code .= chr($char);
}

echo "The code is $code\n";
```

With this offset, 1 gives 'ghep', 2 gives 'tw70', 3 gives 'ob0c'.  To increase the number of characters, change the `$i<4` to a 5, or 13.  To change the included characters, use a different range of [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the first link too and had little success with the code provided. I did some research and I think that YouTube IDs are basically just randomly generated strings (given that there are nearly 74 quintillion possible combinations, the chances of two IDs ever being alike is very slim). Below is a little PHP script that I use to create 11-character YouTube-style random IDs.

```
$length = 11;
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-';

$random_id = "";

for ($i = 0; $length > $i; $i++) {
    $random_id .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) -1)];
}
```

The script above basically creates a list of 64 characters identical to those used by YouTube, randomly selects eleven of those characters and then concatenates them all within a for loop. I then store the random IDs generated in a column for random IDs which are searched for via the URL. It does not include encryption, but it is the closest thing I could come up with. You can change the length of the string by changing the $length variable and the characters used by changing the characters that make up the $characters variable.

Little hint, if you are using a MySQL database, change the random ID column's collation to latin1_bin, that way you can include case sensitivity.